# Will a pre-defined Brush follow changes in Windows color scheme?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Let's say I have the following code:

```
  Dim _Brush_Disabled As New SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.GrayText))
  Dim _Brush_Enabled As New SolidBrush(Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.WindowText))

  Sub Do_Something()
    '
    ' ... _Brush_Disabled and _Brush_Enabled are repeatedly used in this sub
    '
  End Sub
```

Will `_Brush_Disabled` and `_Brush_Enabled` automatically change their colors if the Windows color scheme changes?

If not, how can I make them 'track' Windows color scheme changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't automatically update for you. You can listen for the [WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event on your main window (or where ever your brushes are defined) to know when to update.

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE&namespace=%5BAll%5D).

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much! That's just what the doctor ordered! :D